# timeout dynamic HTTP outbound gateway request-factory

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have configured timeouts for the HTTP Outbound Gateway providing a reference to a ClientHttpRequestFactory bean using the request-factory attribute:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="channelGetByCustomer"
    request-factory="requestFactoryGetByCustomer"
    reply-channel="jsonToObjectChannel" url="${getbycustomer.endpoint.url}"
    http-method="GET" expected-response-type="com.mbracero.integration.dto.Item[]">

    <int-http:uri-variable name="customerid" expression="payload.customerid"/>

</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<beans:bean id="requestFactoryGetByCustomer" class="org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <beans:property name="connectTimeout" value="${getbycustomer.timeout}"/>
    <beans:property name="readTimeout" value="${getbycustomer.timeout}"/>
</beans:bean>
```

But I want to load these attributes dynamically from DDBB (or programmatically) and not from Spring initial boot.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatically you can do that just from any your service injecting that `requestFactoryGetByCustomer` bean and using its setters:

```
@Autowired
private SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactoryGetByCustomer;

....

this.requestFactoryGetByCustomer.setConnectTimeout(30_000);
```

To read those options from the DB and populate them to the bean definition using Spring Container features (e.g. Property Placeholder like in your current case) you should take a look to the [`Commons Configuration`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) framework and populate `Properties` object from the DB `SELECT`.

Comment: But how can I set that to Outbound-gateway? Currently my gateway is in XML, have I change this to Java?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. Your service to set properties and `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` will just share the same object and changes from the first one will impact the last one. Your XML configuration remains as is.

Comment: The `@Gateway` isn't related to the question at all. Please, don't mix concerns. You asked about `connectTimeout` for the `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` I've answered. I don't understand how `@Gateway` may relate: that option is a part of the factory for HTTP request, not your messaging process.

Comment: Yes, I thought it could setear through the gateway, and, as usual, is not possible