# Dynamic timeout for dynamic url http-outbound-gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I hava a http-outbound-gateway that uses dynamic urls with connection and read timeout

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="request"
        reply-channel="response" url-expression="headers.serviceUrl" http-method="POST"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String" charset="UTF-8" request-factory="httpOutboundRequestFactoryBean" message-converters="messageConverterList" header-mapper="headerMapperBean"/>

<bean id="httpOutboundRequestFactoryBean"
      class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
        <property name="readTimeout" value="5000"/>
        <property name="connectTimeout" value="1000"/>
</bean>
```

Is it possible to config a specific timeout according to the url defined in *headers.serviceUrl*?

I searched around and found only this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793760/timeout-dynamic-http-outbound-gateway-request-factory).

One workaround could be to use directly RestTemplate and create a RestTemplate instance every time and set dynamically the requestFactory (with timeout) according to the url, but maybe there is a built-in way of doing this with spring integration

thanks in advance!

**EDIT: ADD ANSWER**

I've added this service activator just before the http-outbound-gateway

```
public class ThreadLocalSample {

public static ThreadLocal<Integer> serviceTimeout = new ThreadLocal<>();

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThreadLocalSample.class);

public Message<?> setTimeout(final Message<?> message){
    final int number = (new Random().nextInt(20 - 1 + 1) + 1)*1000;
    serviceTimeout.set(number);
    LOGGER.info("Service timeout thread local: "+number);

    return message;
}
```

Extended the HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory and override the merge configuration using the threadlocal timeout:

```
public class MyHttpConnectionFactory extends HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory {

private RequestConfig requestConfig;

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyHttpConnectionFactory.class);


@Override
protected RequestConfig createRequestConfig(final Object client) {
    this.requestConfig = super.createRequestConfig(client);
    return this.requestConfig;
}

@Override
protected RequestConfig mergeRequestConfig(final RequestConfig clientConfig) {
    if (this.requestConfig == null) {  // nothing to merge
        return clientConfig;
    }

    final RequestConfig.Builder builder = RequestConfig.copy(clientConfig);
    final int connectTimeout = this.requestConfig.getConnectTimeout();
    if (connectTimeout >= 0) {
        builder.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
    }
    final int connectionRequestTimeout = this.requestConfig.getConnectionRequestTimeout();
    if (connectionRequestTimeout >= 0) {
        builder.setConnectionRequestTimeout(connectionRequestTimeout);
    }
    final int socketTimeout = ThreadLocalSample.serviceTimeout.get();
    LOGGER.info("Service timeout: "+socketTimeout);
    if (socketTimeout >= 0) {
        builder.setSocketTimeout(socketTimeout);
    }
    return builder.build();
}
```

}

The spring integration flow modified:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="request"
        reply-channel="response" url-expression="headers.serviceUrl" http-method="POST"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String" charset="UTF-8" request-factory="httpOutboundRequestFactoryBean" message-converters="messageConverterList" header-mapper="headerMapperBean"/>

<bean id="httpOutboundRequestFactoryBean"
      class="sample.MyHttpConnectionFactory">
        <property name="readTimeout" value="5000"/>
        <property name="connectTimeout" value="1000"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is no and I doubt that we are going to do anything on the matter in the framework. Spring Integration fully relies on the `ClientHttpRequestFactory` and its contract. Therefore maximum what we can suggest is something custom, extending that your `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`.

If we take a look into source code of this factory, we find something like this:

```
public ClientHttpRequest createRequest(URI uri, HttpMethod httpMethod) throws IOException {
    HttpClient client = getHttpClient();

    HttpUriRequest httpRequest = createHttpUriRequest(httpMethod, uri);
    postProcessHttpRequest(httpRequest);
    HttpContext context = createHttpContext(httpMethod, uri);
    if (context == null) {
        context = HttpClientContext.create();
    }

    // Request configuration not set in the context
    if (context.getAttribute(HttpClientContext.REQUEST_CONFIG) == null) {
        // Use request configuration given by the user, when available
        RequestConfig config = null;
        if (httpRequest instanceof Configurable) {
            config = ((Configurable) httpRequest).getConfig();
        }
        if (config == null) {
            config = createRequestConfig(client);
        }
        if (config != null) {
            context.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.REQUEST_CONFIG, config);
        }
    }
```

So, every time the `createRequest()` is called it consults with something like `HttpContext` and/or `RequestConfig`.

So, as a solution for your requirement I would suggest to deal with `ThreadLocal` which you populate before the mentioned `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` and read from that custom `createHttpContext()` or `createRequestConfig()`.

Comment: Yes, that's only the way to transfer data from one component to another if we don't have an access. The static methods to read/write to/from `ThreadLocal` are savers. See `SecurityContextHolder` in Spring Security with its `ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy` implementaiton. And also `RequestContextHolder` in Spring Web.

Comment: I'll see them. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, forgot :)

Comment: Hi Artem, do you have an example of how to use a ThredLocal here?

Comment: You create some `public static ThredLocal` property in some class populate its value in the Service Activator before sending a message to the HTTP Outbound Gateway. In the code of custom `createHttpContext()` you get access to that `ThredLocal` variable. The point is that it is really thread-safe and won't affect any other calls to your HTTP gateway. You only need to be sure that population into a `ThredLocal` and its read have to be done in the same thread.

Comment: Thanks Artem! I've edited the original post with the solution. Could you please confirm to me, it is what you told me? Sorry to ask for this, but I am new with ThreadLocal usage.